# Add and trace unhearable Noises or Markers to a Video Clip

Tags: java, audio, video

I'm trying to write an application which adds some noises (or markers) to various parts of a Video Clip and trigger an action once a section (marker) been reached.

I think using technologies like Audio Stenography cannot help this purpose. As far I understood it, It hides a text value in unused sections of a WAV file and extract them from a file.

I also learned that any frequencies under 20 Hz and upper 20KHz cannot be heared by a human ear. Using a Audio Analysis library like [musicg](http://code.google.com/p/musicg/),

gave me an idea to recognize and encode those frequencies with some algorithms like FFT and trigger an action based on that encoded unhearable frequency.

That was all I could find out after a week of investigation and unfortunately don't know further and will appreciate if somebody have had a similar experience in this field and can help me.

Comment: FFT stores selected frequencies, i.e. only those in the range of human hearing.

Comment: good point, I didn't aware of that, thank you. It seems that I must search for completely another algorithem.

Comment: You might be able to encode things in frequencies you can hear but as not noticeable to a human.  You would have to experiment with this.  BTW adults have trouble hearing the higher frequencies but these are often recorded anyway.  e.g. you can have a ring tone only teenagers and children can hear.

Comment: http://icwales.icnetwork.co.uk/business-in-wales/business-news/tm_objectid=16358968&method=full&siteid=50082&headline=life-s-a-buzz-for-mosquito-inventor-name_page.html